# Flutter | Receive error 403 after sending requests to server

Tags: php, flutter, http, flutter-dependencies

I developed a chat system the chat window of the chat I connected to Stream and at the bottom Navigation Bar I put a text box with a button that is connected to a function for sending a message via HTTP package. When I send a message it appears in the chat window but when I send about 4 messages the server returns an error 403.

The chat system I built is connected in a stream to the api I created in PHP from there it takes the information stored within the SQL.

Anyone have an idea how to fix this bug of error 403 or maybe an idea how to improve the system?

Thank you !

PHP Code :

```
if ($do == "get_msg_chat")  
    {
        header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        $id = htmlspecialchars($mysqli->escape_string($_POST['id'])); 
        $id_event = htmlspecialchars($mysqli>escape_string($_POST['id_event'])); 
        $msg = htmlspecialchars($mysqli->escape_string($_POST['msg'])); 
        $select1 = ("SELECT user_name FROM `users` WHERE id = '".$id."' LIMIT 1"); 
        $number = $mysqli->query($select1);
        $rows = $number->num_rows;
        $row = $number->fetch_assoc();
        if($rows < 1)
        {exit("");} 
        else
        {
            $selectsql = ("select chat from events where id = '".$id_event."' LIMIT 1");
            $result = $mysqli->query($selectsql);
            $msg1 = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $audio_ar = array();
            $audio_ar = (array) json_decode($msg1['chat']);
            $msg = str_replace("\'", "&apos;", $msg);
            $roy = array(
                'chat' => $msg,
                'user' => $row['user_name'], 
                'date' => $datenew,
                'time' => $newtime,
            );
            
            $audio_ar[] = $roy;
            $jsonpush = json_encode($audio_ar, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            $update = ("UPDATE `events` SET `chat`= '".$jsonpush."' WHERE id = '".$id_event."' ");
            $mysqli->query($update);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That means the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it, so I think it's an issue at the backend

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited my question and added the PHP code